# segmentation fault for the simplest program?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am just starting out, but this piece of code is giving me a 'segmentation fault' and I can't find out what's wrong with it:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void) {


 int number = 0;
 int lastDigit = 0;

 printf("Enter an integer: ");
 scanf("%d", number);

 number = number*10;

 printf("Number times ten is %d.\n", number);

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: scanf is not simple and neither is printf, you need to understand quite a bit before you can use either correctly compared with the equivalant in C++ say cout << or java System.out.println(object);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`scanf("%d", number)` is being given the `int` itself, but actually needs a **pointer to** the `int`.  Try `scanf("%d", &number)`

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%d", number);
```

would be

```
scanf("%d", &number);
```

Note the ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

use "&" to store a value after scanning.

```
scanf("%d", &number);
```